# Findall across multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, findall

```
data = {'Cat':  ['A Phaser','A','B Phaser','B','B','B'],
        'L1': ['Phase','xyzss','xyzss','Phase','xyzss','xyzss'],
        'L2': ['xyzss','Stage','xyzss','xyzss','Phase2','xyzss'],
        'L3': ['xyzss','xyzss','xyzss','xyzss','xyzss','Step'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Cat','L1','L2','L3'])

def funt(s):
    if re.findall(r'Phase', s, re.IGNORECASE):
        return 'Phase'
    elif re.findall(r'Stag', s, re.IGNORECASE): 
        return 'Stage'
    elif re.findall(r'Step', s, re.IGNORECASE): 
        return 'Step'
    
df[['L1','L2','L3']].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1).apply(lambda x : funt(x))
```

Output:

```
0    Phase
1    Stage
2     None
3    Phase
4    Phase
5     Step
dtype: object
```

I am wondering if there is another way of approaching this like a way of applying `findall` across columns without joining columns together?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your source code has syntax errors and is incomplete, please post the actual code you're having issues with.

Comment: Try this: ``df.apply(lambda df: df.str.extract(r'(Phase.*|Stage.*)', expand=False)).ffill(1).iloc[:, -1]``
``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter required rows. Using replace, null the xyzss. Stack and reset index and you have your outcome as a pd. Series.

Option 1: If `xyzss` does not vary:   `df['filter']=df.iloc[:,1:4].replace({'xyzss':np.nan}).stack().reset_index(drop=True)`

Option 1: If `xyzss` varies:

```
df.join(pd.Series(df.mask(~df.isin(pat), np.nan).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True),name='filter'))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot null 'xyzss' as it is different values in actual dataframe.

Comment: We havent said, you null in the original. This is just a computation that results in the outcome. Can make it be output as a column if you wanted or even list

Comment: sorry, maybe i am not reading it right.....don't we `replace({'xyzss':np.nan})` is to null all values, then stack? in the actual dataframe, values are different so I can't do replace({'xyzss':np.nan})

Comment: I see, so you need`pat=['Phase','Stage','Step','Phase2']` and `df.mask(~df.isin(pat), np.nan).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`?